# How to import/add icons from the icon pack/template pack into my android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've downloaded the icons pack and the template pack from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack
and the icon pack and other stuff from here: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html.

I don't know how to put them in my app.
Is it in the code?

Answer (score 2):

It must be in `res/` folder of your project.

Put all of them in drawable folders of the project and then they can be accesses using `R.drawable.file_name`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put them inside your `res/drawable` and use them in your app. You can either put them in your xml file or you can add them programatically.

Once inside the `drawable`, they can be accessed throug `@drawable/resourcename` in the xml file. eg,

```
android:background="@drawable/image1"
```

When doing it programatically, what we do is we set an `imageview` and load the drawable resource into the imageview.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
iv.setImageDrawable(image);//where image is a drawable object
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) would be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the launch icon of your APP, you should put your icons into res/drawable-ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi or -xhdpi.

Then create a folder, called drawable in res folder and add there images. then you may use them from XML by calling: android:src"@drawable/imagename.png" or programmatically getDrawable(*drawable ID*). You may also put your pictures into assets.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the `res/` folder and go to `new->other`.

Expand the Android folder and click android Icon set, then click next and follow the wizard all the way through.

Then you can do a clean and rebuild and they should be available!