# Add Android icon pack to project

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I've downloaded the Action Bar Icon Pack for Android.

The icons I need are in `Action_Bar_Icons` and `Navigation_Drawer_Indicator`. There are loads of files in there. Do I have to copy the pngs one by one and in the right **dpi folder, or is there a quicker/easier way?

The directory structure is like:

```
├── Navigation_Drawer_Indicator
│   ├── holo_dark
│   │   ├── drawable-hdpi
│   │   │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│   │   │   └── ic_drawer.png
│   │   ├── drawable-mdpi
│   │   │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│   │   │   └── ic_drawer.png
│   │   ├── drawable-xhdpi
│   │   │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│   │   │   └── ic_drawer.png
│   │   └── drawable-xxhdpi
│   │       ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│   │       └── ic_drawer.png
│   └── holo_light
│       ├── drawable-hdpi
│       │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│       │   └── ic_drawer.png
│       ├── drawable-mdpi
│       │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│       │   └── ic_drawer.png
│       ├── drawable-xhdpi
│       │   ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│       │   └── ic_drawer.png
│       └── drawable-xxhdpi
│           ├── drawer_shadow.9.png
│           └── ic_drawer.png
└── Navigation_Drawer_Indicator.ai
```

and for `Action_Bar_Icons` is MUCH larger...

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709255/how-to-import-add-icons-from-the-icon-pack-template-pack-into-my-android-app), but it's not really answering in a way I understand.

Comment: You do need to copy them manually into the correct dpi folders. There is no easier way.

Comment: I don't know easier way ...

Comment: How about the hold_* themes? Should I copy just the resources for the theme I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy just the drawable-DPI folders into the existing folder-structure it will simply copy all the elements into the folders instead the folder itself(well, if the folder doesn't exist, it will copy the folder as well)

Comment: Yeah you can merge the two folders